# Unable to find Nginx (centos)

Tags: linux, nginx, centos

i am trying to uninstall nginx in centos 7 , 
i have tried following commands 
Yum uninstall nginx

also tried "sudo systemctl stop nginx.service" this stop services but did not work for me.
i have followed this as well https://webhostinggeeks.com/howto/how-to-remove-uninstall-nginx-on-centos-7-rhel-7-oracle-linux-7/

When I type nginx
Then bash outputs command not found

But when I type
ps aux -P | grep nginx 
i found many nginx running task
[Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFce2.png)
 when i search for nginx in directory i did not find nginx there. i looked in 
/etc/nginx (rpm-save is found here) 
/usr/nginx (nginx directory is missing)
/usr/sbin/nginx (nginx directory is missing)

still found one nginx on going process
[nginx running process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WjYE.png)

Comment: What do you mean with "this stops services _but did not work for me." Why did it not work? Did you get any output? What do the logs show?

Comment: i want to stop all nginx services is used this commad "sudo systemctl stop nginx.service" it did not give any error but its not working or stop nginx services

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer.

I believe that nginx is only running in memory in that stage and that you have deleted all its files, but here are the steps I would take if I was in your situation.

First I would install a package called mlocate which will index your disks and will help you find files much quicker than using `find` for example:

```
yum install mlocate -y
```

When it finishes installing the package, run the following command to index your disks:

```
updatedb
```

When that finishes, run:

```
locate nginx
```

Delete whatever files you find.

Then, run:

```
ps -ef | grep nginx | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

The above command will parse all the process ids of nginx and kill them.

Then, if you want to be thorough, verify that there are no open files held by nginx:

```
lsof -nP | grep nginx
```

And to kill their processes:

```
lsof -nP | grep nginx | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

**Edit:**

Following @lain's comment, you can do it by using `find` and `pkill` as well.

```
find / -name nginx\* -delete

pkill -9 nginx
```

Comment: You could just use `find` and `pkill` too ?

Comment: That's true :) I forget about `pkill` sometimes.

Comment: i found nginx /var/lib/nginx , should i delete nginx folder?

Comment: If your intention is to remove nginx completely then yes, delete it.

Comment: I had found many nginx on going process after deleting nginx locating path i still found one on goind process which i have mentioned above